# Django: How to convert "1 day, 1:00:09" in "HH:MM:SS" format

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have time in seconds. To convert it into the "HH:MM: SS" format used

```
      hour = forDuration.strftime('%H:%M:%S', forDuration.gmtime(seconds))
```

but I got this value: 1 day, 1:00:09. Are there any other options to get an hour in this format "HH:MM: SS"

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to format **forDuration** variable with **time**

```
forDuration = time.gmtime(seconds) # dont forget to import time
formatted_time = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', forDuration)
```